# how to set export file name for a report in stimulsoft?

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I make a report in Stimulsoft by using Stiwebviewer I show it in aspx file. Now I want to set Report filename that used in export, for example when I export the report to pdf...default name is Report(1).pdf.And I want to change it to Sedi.pdf.
I try this:

`StiWebViewer1.ServerReportName = "Sedi";`

But it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string reportName = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Mainreport = (StiReport)Session["SelectedReport"];
        this.reportName = (string)Session["ReportName"];
        StiWebViewer1.Report = this.Mainreport;
        StiWebViewer1.DataBind();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string iQueryString = Request.QueryString["sti_StiWebViewer1_export"];
            if (iQueryString != null) this.SaveFile(iQueryString);
        }
    }
    private void SaveFile(string iQueryString)
    {
        if (this.reportName == null) this.reportName = "Report";
        MemoryStream mes = new MemoryStream();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        switch (iQueryString)
        {
            #region Cases
            case "SaveAdobePdf":
                {
                    this.Mainreport.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Pdf, mes);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + this.reportName + ".Pdf");
                }
                break;
            case "SaveMicrosoftXps":
                {
                    this.Mainreport.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Xps, mes);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + this.reportName + ".Xps");
                }
                break;
                #endregion
        }
        mes.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        mes.Close();
    }
```